# Problem with URLWithString: when string contains Arab chars

Tags: ios, nsurl

I have problem with my code when path contains Arab chars. In this case URLWithString always returns nil.

```
NSString *path = self.currentlySelectedBlogItem.linkUrl;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Solution is simple:
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Instead of putting the solution in as a comment, please put it as an answer and mark it as the correct answer so it doesn't look like an open question.

Comment: Actually just use google instead of posting a duplicate question please.

Answer (score 2):

You have to Use UTF8 encoding for special characters:

```
NSString *path = self.currentlySelectedBlogItem.linkUrl;

NSString *encodedPath = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedPath];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```